# imitate XD's "snap" animation using css transitions

Tags: css, frontend, css-animations, adobe-xd

In this video is a prototype made with Adobe XD.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scrvo.jpg

I am trying to reproduce the "Snap" animation used to make that effect soft bounce in css but i cant get it just right.

Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/etw3qy48/2/

`transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.30, 0.265, 1.30);`

I need help reproducing the soft bounce animation (AKA "snap" in XD) as seen in the video with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your fiddle and the video, the only real difference I see is that your animation bounces both on start and on end, when you only want it to bounce at the end of the transition. Firefox has a really cool transition cubic-bezier editor, this is what I came up with:

```css
transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.18,.89,.45,1.36);
```

Comment: I just cant pull off the smoothness of XDs animation. Is there another css property or javascript approach that can do it more like XD?